# RabbitMQ exceptions when installing through Chef

Tags: rabbitmq, ubuntu-12.04, chef-infra, apt

I have a very simple chef recipe which attempts to install RabbitMQ and several RabbitMQ Plugins on an EC2 & Vagrant VM (both running Ubuntu 12.04).

I'm using the OpsCode RabbitMQ cookbook (https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/rabbitmq), and when I provision the machine(s) I get the following stack trace:

```
INFO: Processing apt_repository[rabbitmq] action add (rabbitmq::default line 43)
INFO: Processing remote_file[/srv/chef/file_store/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc] action create (/srv/chef/file_store/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 36)
INFO: remote_file[/srv/chef/file_store/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc] updated
INFO: remote_file[/srv/chef/file_store/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc] mode changed to 644
INFO: Processing execute[install-key rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc] action run (/srv/chef/file_store/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 52)
INFO: execute[install-key rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc] ran successfully
INFO: apt_repository[rabbitmq] sending run action to execute[apt-get update] (immediate)
INFO: Processing execute[apt-get update] action run (apt::default line 29)
INFO: execute[apt-get update] ran successfully
INFO: Processing remote_file[/srv/chef/file_store/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc] action nothing (/srv/chef/file_store/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 36)
INFO: Processing execute[install-key rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc] action nothing (/srv/chef/file_store/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 52)
INFO: Processing execute[apt-get update] action nothing (/srv/chef/file_store/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 78)
INFO: Processing file[/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq-source.list] action create (/srv/chef/file_store/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 89)
INFO: file[/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq-source.list] created file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq-source.list
INFO: Processing package[util-linux] action install (rabbitmq::default line 53)
INFO: Processing package[rabbitmq-server] action install (rabbitmq::default line 54)
ERROR: package[rabbitmq-server] (rabbitmq::default line 54) has had an error
...
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: package[rabbitmq-server] (rabbitmq::default line 54) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: apt-get -q -y install rabbitmq-server=2.7.1-0ubuntu4 returned 100, expected 0
```

As you can see by the logs the `apt-get update` is happening before the new rabbitmq source is added (meaning it tries to install rabbitmq-server version 2.7.1 vs. the 2.8.x version from the RabbitMQ repository.

This is the cookbook code: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/rabbitmq/blob/master/recipes/default.rb#L43-54

Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the 2 fixes you need.

apt_repository wasn't kicking off a proper apt-get update when new repos were added. 
http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-1530 has the fix.

rabbitmq's apt_repository wasn't triggering the apt-get update
http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-1496 with the apt cookbook update fixes it. This was merged to https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/rabbitmq master today.

New releases of the 2 cookbooks should fix everything, hopefully this week. Feel free to grab from github in the meantime and ping me with any further questions.

matt@opscode

Comment: Unfortunately, those patches don't fix the issue at hand. I've posted  detail on how to recreate on this gist: https://gist.github.com/3345845

Comment: For those who experience the same issue, this was resolved by including the patches above and upgrading Chef-Client to 0.10.12